# custom field in product type not showing in line item drupal

Tags: commerce

ive created custom fields in my product type.

[image]

then i have this code under my custom module

```
global $user;
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
if($order) {
     $line_item_list = $order->commerce_line_items["und"];
     foreach ($line_item_list as $key => $value) {
         $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($value["line_item_id"]);
         drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($line_item, TRUE) . '</pre>');
     }
}
```

i tried to print per line item to, but i cant see my custom field in the print...

anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the fields to the commerce product entity (`commerce_product`), not the line item entity (`commerce_line_item`).

That is why the fields don't show on your line item entity.

The line item entity contains a product reference field (`commerce_product`) referencing the associated product, you will need to inspect that to get the fields from the product.

e.g:

```
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
// Get product field value from line item
foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
  // If line item is a commerce product type
  if (in_array($line_item_wrapper->type->value(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {
    // Fetch duration value on product.
    $duration = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_subscription_duration_2->value();
    // Get raw values
    // $duration = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_subscription_duration_2->raw();
    drupal_set_message($duration);
  }
}
```

Comment: you have point there! :) thanks.. but how come i cant print the variable $duration? it doesnt print anything.. thank you.

Comment: your answer was useful, i edited it a little for it to work in mine, here's my code `$duration = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->value()->field_subscription_duration_2["und"]["0"]["value"];` thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, please marked solved if suitable thanks. Note you can also use `$line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_subscription_duration_2->raw();` to get the raw field values.

Comment: Use: `$line_item_wrapper->getBundle()` instead of `$line_item_wrapper->type->value()` as it could cause some issues like `Unable to get the data property type as the parent data structure is not set`.